# Std::stoul not being catched after failing in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I am new to C++ and am probably missing something obvious. I want to converse OCT and HEX numbers to DEC. I can get all kinds of wrong inputs, so instead of many conditions I wanted to make the conversion with std::stoul and catch when it fails.

The point of the method is to get 3 numbers in a string. First is in OCT, second in DEC and the third in HEX. I need to check if they are the same value or not.

I get the numbers from a vector *vec* of strings, but that is working fine and I don't think the problem is there.

Problem is that whenever the method fails (for example "88" for OCT) the whole test fails and it is not going into the catch block.

This is my code:

```
bool validate_line(const std::string& str) {
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::string tmp;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++){
        if(str.at(i) == ' '){
            vec.push_back(tmp);
            tmp = "";
        }
        else {
            tmp += str.at(i);
            if(i + 1 == str.size()) vec.push_back(tmp);
        }
    }
    if(vec.size() != 3) return false;

    //1 - Octan number
    unsigned long octDec;
    try {
        octDec = std::stoul(vec.at(1), nullptr, 8);
    }
    catch(const std::invalid_argument& ia){
        return false;
    }

    //2 - Decimal
    int dec = atoi( vec.at(2).c_str() );

    //3 - Hex number
    std::string h = vec.at(3).c_str();
    unsigned long hexDec;
    try{
    hexDec = std::stoul(h, nullptr, 16);
    }
    catch(const std::invalid_argument& ia) {
        return false;
    }

    if(octDec == dec && dec == hexDec) return true;
    return false;
}
```

These are examples of my tests for this method. First one is ok. The rest should end in the catch blocks.

```
TEST_CASE("Line validation", "[small1]") {

    GIVEN("complex improperly tagged equal string") {
        CHECK(validate_line("0111 73 0x49"));
    }

    GIVEN("string not conforming to format -- bad number format") {
        CHECK(!validate_line("88 88 0x58"));
    }

    GIVEN("string not conforming to format -- not numbers") {
        CHECK(!validate_line("07 7 G"));
    }
}
```

Comment: most of the time the error is in the code where you least expect it. Anyhow you need to provide a [mcve]. How do you know that no excpetion is thrown/catched?

Comment: I have a test method. So whenever test with bad input comes, it fails on the line with std:stoul instead of going into the catch block.

Comment: As I wrote, for example for OCT I send in "88" which is not octan number. Then it should fail and it indeed does, but it is not catching any exception. Or for HEX I can send in something like "2x". That kind of stuff is what I am trying to get rid of.

Comment: I edited the original post and added more info and code.

Comment: I added the tests I am using into the original post.

Comment: I do NOT catch the exception! Thats is the problem the whole time. If I debug and go line by line, when I am on the line with the std::stoul it just ends there and the test automatically fails without returning false and therefore being ok. It is about the catch block the whole time.

Comment: cleaned the spam a bit. I think I found the issue. writing an answer...

Comment: `std::stoul("88", nullptr, 8);` sure does throw - verified with https://www.onlinegdb.com

Comment: btw you need to be more specific on what output you get and what ouput you expect. I am still not sure what you get and what you expect. I hope the answer isnt completely off

Answer (score 2):

Your code always returns at the following line:

```
if(vec.size() != 4) return false;
```

so the function that can throw is never called.

The `vec.size()` at that point is always 3 for all your test inputs.

**UPDATE:**

OP changed the line of code in question to

```
if(vec.size() != 3) return false;
```

after this answer was already posted.

Comment: Sorry, this was just a misstype in the code I showed. It is not the real problem. I have corrected it in the original post.

Comment: Please don't alter your question after there is already a valid answer (to the original question), or at least remark it somehow that you altered your question, with e.g. an *UPDATE:* section

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed in the compiler. I use CLion and when debugging it does not show the step into catch block if there is only a return statement. There really is not any problem with the code.